# Is there an endpoint to activate "file finder" for github

Tags: github-api

I’m pretty new to GitHub.
Is it possible to get the list of files in the specific branch.
The endpoint I have been using is https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/contents?ref=/master.
The problem with this is that it returns even folders. I only want files, like they appear when using GitHub UI File Finder.
Thanks in advance!